# Using the general solution for solve $\sin x = \sin y$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

We know that $\sin x = \sin y$ implies that $x = 2k\pi + y$ or $x = 2k\pi + \pi - y$. If we want to solve $\sin x = \sin x$ using this method, it gives $x = 2k\pi + x$ or $x = 2k\pi + \pi - x$ but it's obvious that solution is $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Why this happens? There is a similar problem for $\cos x = \cos x$.

Comment: $x = 2 k \pi + x$ Implies $2 k \pi = 0$, implying $k = 0$. This tells us nothing about which $x$'s are solutions. Furthermore, $x = 2k\pi + \pi - x$ implies $x = k \pi$, which is indeed a solution for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, but not all solutions.

Comment: $\sin x=\sin x$ holds for all (real or complex) numbers $x$.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik So we can conclude $x \in \mathbb{R}$ from $x = 2k\pi + x$?

Comment: No, but you can say that $\sin(x+2\pi) = \sin(x)$ . It is obvious as $\sin$ has a period of $2\pi$.

Comment: @Ak19 How we can show that all of real numbers are solutions?

Comment: $\sin x = \sin x \implies \sin x - \sin x = 2\sin(0)\cos(x) = 0 \implies 0\cos (x) = 0 $ which holds $\forall x \in \Bbb{C}$

Comment: @Ak19 Okay but if we use that solution we have $k = 0$ and then $x = x$ which holds $\forall x \in \Bbb{R}$. Why this argument is false?

Comment: @S.H.W Which argument ?

Comment: @Ak19 $\sin x = \sin x$ implies $x = 2k\pi + x$. Then we have $k = 0$ and so $x = x$. This last equality holds for all real numbers. Therefore for all real numbers $\sin x = \sin x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is in the difference between an identity and an equation.

For example $$ (x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$$ is an identity but $$(x+1)^2=16$$ is an equation.

The identity $$\sin x= \sin x $$ holds for every $x$ just like the identity $x=x$ and it does not require solving.

On the other hand the equation $$\sin x = \sin y$$ admits solutions because it is not true for all $x$ and $y$

We solve equations and find solutions because not every number satisfies an equation.

On the other hand we prove the identities and they are satisfied for all numbers.

Comment: That is true but why $\sin x = \sin x$ is an identity? You should prove that.

Comment: It's an identity because both sides of the equation are the exact same function. This trivially makes the 'equation' an identity. Any 'equation' of the form $f(x)=f(x)$ admits solutions $x\in D$ where $D$ is the domain of the function $f(x)$.

Comment: @S.H.W. There is in fact a difference between the identity $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ and the identity $\sin x = \sin x$. The former must be proved since we have different expressions on each side. The latter is however trivial since it has the same expression on both sides.

Comment: @md2perpe After spending many years to learn math, I don't know what is trivial really.

Comment: @PeterForeman I understand your point but I don't know whether it needs a proof or not.

Comment: @S.H.W $\forall x\in A$ we have that $\exists y\in B:f(x)=y$ where the function $f:A\mapsto B$ has domain $A$ and co-domain $B$. As $y$ is a constant our 'equation' is equivalent to $y=y$ which is trivially true. Hence the 'equation' is true $\forall x\in A$.

Comment: @PeterForeman Okay, thanks. The argument which I wrote in the comments is true?

Comment: @S.H.W Yes, but there is no need to translate the identity into the form $x=x$, it is trivially true for all $x$ in the domain of $f(x)$.

Comment: @PeterForeman I've got it. Really grateful for your help.